# install poblems cwp and maria DB

Tags: cwp

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please use https://bugs.centos.org/.

mariadb/primary_db             FAILED
http://yum.mariadb.org/10.4/centos7-amd64/repodata/fc315dc4fcba52f06fc938a9fa824d0ddf335f1ee86eba3798c538c4ff0fdc4a-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
mariadb/primary_db             FAILED
http://yum.mariadb.org/10.4/centos7-amd64/repodata/fc315dc4fcba52f06fc938a9fa824d0ddf335f1ee86eba3798c538c4ff0fdc4a-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
http://yum.mariadb.org/10.4/centos7-amd64/repodata/fc315dc4fcba52f06fc938a9fa824d0ddf335f1ee86eba3798c538c4ff0fdc4a-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.